# DoReferenceTransaction API for PayPal

Tags: paypal, checkout, paypal-sandbox

Does DoReferenceTransaction API work with any PayPal account? I'm trying to implement something similar to the one-click buy option seen in Amazon (not recurring billing). Finance still has to get back to me on the type on account we have (Standard, Pro etc). Does the DoReferenceTransaction API work with all types of paypal accounts?

Also, am a bit confused by the types of accounts PayPal has. On PayPal's site I see only Website Payments Standard and Express Checkout. But I hear a lot of conversation about Payment Pro and Payflow Pro and all that. Not sure which is which.

Any inputs/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoReferenceTransaction will work fine with Standard PayPal accounts but only with Express Checkout.  If you want to work with credit cards directly you'd have to go with Payments Pro.

If you are going to use DRT with EC then you'll need get it approved by PayPal before it'll be available, but it doesn't cost anything extra.

PayPal has recently made some changes to "Payments Pro" that are causing lots of confusion.  "Website Payments Pro" is the "old" version that uses the DoDirectPayment API.

"Payments Pro" (without the Website at the beginning) is the "new" version and it works on the PayFlow Gateway.

Depending on how old your account is and how you go about applying for Pro you'll get put into one or the other.  They're trying to get everybody on PayFlow now, but sometimes they can't depending on variables in play.

If you do get into the new version of Payments Pro you would actually have access to every API on PayFlow and the standard PayPal gateway, but you would have to get them to enable everything for you.